# PHP - how to truncate a string formed by a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, truncate, strlen

Say I have the following loop in my view

```
foreach ($value as $row):
     echo $row['name'] . ', ';
endforeach;
```

This outputs a string like this in my browser

> Geddy, Lee, Neil, Peart, Alex,

I wonder if anyone can suggest a method to truncate this string at `n` characters, for example

> Geddy, Lee, Ne...

Since the string is being output from the loop I am unsure how to wrap a truncate function around this `foreach`.

Thanks for helping!

*sample truncate function*

```
function truncate_text($text, $nbrChar, $append='...') {
     if(strlen($text) > $nbrChar) {
          $text = substr($text, 0, $nbrChar);
          $text .= $append;
     }
     return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not save the row values to a variable and truncate that variable and just echo that?

```
var $str = "";
foreach ($value as $row):
     $str .= $row['name'] . ', ';
endforeach;

echo truncate_text($str, 'whatever');
```

Answer (score 2):

First up, the `foreach` is not required.  Second, we can then truncate it if required quite simply.

```
// Maximum length of the string; note that this does not include the '...'
$length = 20; 

// This is PHP 5.3 only and converts the value array to an array of names 
// $value = array_map(function ($f) { return $f["name"];}, $value);

// This is a PHP 5.2 way to do the array mapping
$value = array_map(create_function('$f', 'return $f["name"];'), $value);

$string = join(', ', $value);
$truncated = (strlen($string) > $length) 
    ? substr($string, 0, $length) . '...' 
    : $string;
```

This also has the benefit of not leaving an ugly trailing comma.

Comment: definitely you will need a way to traverse the array as looks like that is an associative array with more that one key.

Comment: you could also use the $length var in substr($string, 0, $length) to make it more dynamic. +1 for using ternary n not ifs in loopy loops

Comment: @el yobo, the `foreach` i am showing is actually nested in a couple of other `foreach's` so at the end @fourth's solution worked best - thanks for your comment

Comment: @Tapos, fair point.  I've added an array_map call to extract the names.  @Lawrence, yeah, that's actually why I put it there, but forgot to put it in the other bit... thanks :)

Comment: @el yobo - is there a PHP 5.2 way of using your solution? my server is 5.2.14

Comment: You can also just do a loop to make a new array, e.g. `$names = array();  foreach ($value as $foo) { $names[] = $foo['name']; }` and then work with the new array; it might be easier to read than calls to `create_function`, but the availability of lambdas and closures in 5.3 makes `array_map` so much more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function truncate_text($text, $nbrChar, $append='...') {
     if(strlen($text) > $nbrChar) {
          $text = substr($text, 0, $nbrChar);
          $text .= $append;
     }
     return $text;
}
```

and then in the foreach you can do it like this

```
foreach ($value as $row) {
     $name = truncate_text($row['name']);
}
```

now `$name` will output truncated text.

also consider using brackets for loops, or conditions, although it is not necessary but it will help you a lot while debugging the code as using brackets {} can indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `break`

```
$limit = 20;
$str = '';
foreach ($value as $row) {
   if ($str > $limit) {
      $str .= substr($row, 0, $limit) . '...';
      break;
   }
   $str .= "$row, ";
   $limit -= strlen($row);
}
$str = rtrim($str, ', ');
```

The (minor) advantage of this is that you don't have to iterate through the entire row.